# What is the Biblical basis the for Immutable Nature of God?

Tags: biblical-basis, catholicism, catholic-catechism

Dei Filius sayeth this:

> God cannot deny himself, nor can truth ever be in opposition to truth. The appearance of this kind of specious contradiction is chiefly due to the fact that either the dogmas of faith are not understood and explained in accordance with the mind of the Church, or unsound views are mistaken for the conclusions of reason.

and the Catechism quoteth it and sayeth this:

> "because of the authority of God himself who reveals them, who can neither deceive nor be deceived"

Which is something I heardeth a priest say a few days ago in reference to 4th graders asking whether God can make a rock so big he can't lift it.  The Catholic answer is actually no, because God can't change His nature.

So, I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that the Catholic Church's teaching on this is indeed based in Scripture.  But, since the references in the Catechism point to a Vatican I document, I'm not entirely sure which scripture (sounds like something St. Paul would say) or if it is just a teaching that is consistent with scripture.

This is asked in regards to the documents (Dei Filius and CCC 156) and Catholic or Catholic leaning answers would be most appreciated.

Comment: In the answers, it would be important to deal with those verses that seem to show that God can change. (That can be dealt with fairly easily, but it needs to be done for completeness’ sake, it seems to me.) I will take a crack at it, if I have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few verses that support this:

> Jesus Christ is the same yesterday, today, and forever.  Hebrews 13:8 NIV
>
> Of old you laid the foundation of the earth, and the heavens are the
> work of your hands.  They will perish, but you will remain; they will
> all wear out like a garment. You will change them like a robe, and
> they will pass away, but you are the same, and your years have no end.
> Psalm 102:25-27 NIV
>
> For I the LORD do not change; therefore you, O children of Jacob, are not consumed. Malachi 3:6
>
> Every good gift and every perfect gift is from above, coming down from the Father of lights with whom there is no variation or shadow due to change.  James 1:17

Answer (score 2):

I think that Mal 3:6 answer this question straight forward:

> But because I, Adonai, do not change, you sons of Ya`akov will not be
>   destroyed.  (Mal 3:6 CJB)
>
> For I am the LORD, I change not; therefore ye sons of Jacob are not
>   consumed.  (Mal 3:6 KJV)

As Barnes says in his commentary:

> I am the Lord, I change not - , better, more concisely, “I, the Lord 
>   I change not - . The proper name of God, “He who Is,” involves His
>   unchangeableness. For change implies imperfection; it changes to that
>   which is either more perfect or less perfect: to somewhat which that
>   being, who changes, is not or has not. But God has everything in
>   Himself perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

in Hebrews 6:18,my study brought me here to see what meaning
Of  "by two immutable things in which it is impossible for God to lie"
Well Jesus stated in John 14:6, John 16:13, 2Timothy 2:25, Zech.8:3;
In Matt."1:23,& John 1:1, also Is.12:2* John 3:16* Are one in the same.They are unchaning, they are the two immutable.

Comment: My research brought me here looking

Comment: Hebrews 6:18 itself tells you what the two immutable things are: God's promise and God's oath. It's not talking about the trinity.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE. Please take a look at our [about] page.